# How do I center a element with an unknown width?

Tags: html, css, width, center, responsive-design

right at the moment I am coding a responsive design. So there are a couple of elements within the code that are set to a relative or an unknown width.

In this special case I have a section-element which is used for a pager to switch through an unknown number of pages. So its width is undefined.

Due to layout reason the pager has alyways to be placed in the horizontal center of the parent element which is defined by a relative width.

I know how to center elements with absolute and relative widths, but in this case I am a bit helpless. I also searched here and found some posts, but I cannot find a solution that works fine.

Do you have any ideas?

Code:

```
<section class="pager">
    <ul>
        <li><a href=""><span>&laquo;<span> previous</span></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="active"><span>1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>2</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>3</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>4</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>5</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>6</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>7</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>8</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>9</span></a></li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li><a href=""><span>540</span></a></li>        
        <li><a href=""><span>541</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span><span>next </span>&raquo;</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at this fiddle and see if this helps:

http://jsfiddle.net/qQEQ6/

Comment: Helped out very well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
.pager{display:block;width:100%;min-width:200px;margin:0 auto;text-align:center}
```

min-width value is an example, and you adapt the min-width for each resolution

Comment: I tried a couple of combinations of width:100%, text-align:center and margin:0 auto. I also pasted your advice, but it did not work out.